# Random in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I need a function which calculate the capacity.
I want that the function calculate for each Agent(agentOfPopulation) a random numeral between 70 and 90.
My code:

```
int agentOfPopulation; 
for (int i = 0; i < main.agentOfPopulation.size(); i++){
agentOfPopulation = (int) (Math.random()*90+70);
}
```

The code doesn't works.
Has somebody an idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The way your random function is written it will generate numbers between 70 and 159. If you want random numbers between 70 and 90 inclusive, you want:

```
agentOfPopulation = (int) (Math.random()*21+70);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the uniform function

```
agentOfPopulation=uniform(70,90);
```

If you want a discrete number:

```
agentOfPopulation=uniform_discr(70,90);
```